# Questionnaire application choice option values 4 and 5 not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Following image is from my android studio Questionnaire application testing.
For some reason values for `option 4` and `option 5` are not showing up despite numerous attempts to edit the database class and quiz activity class.

[image: app testing image]

The questionnaire application consist of 21 DASS questions with 5 options to choose from but only the 3 answer showing up and not in the order that i want. Question order from top to bottom is like this (Disagree  strongly, Disagree moderately, Neutral, Agree moderately, Agree Strongly ). Below are the Classes used in the process.

DataBase Class

```
public class QuizDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyAwesomeQuiz.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        QuizDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            this.db = db;

            final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                    QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                    QuestionsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
                    QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
                    QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
                    QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
                    QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4 + " TEXT, " +
                    QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION5 + " TEXT, " +
                    QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER" +
                    ")";

            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
            fillQuestionsTable();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        private void fillQuestionsTable() {
            Question q1 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q1);
            Question q2 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q2);
            Question q3 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q3);
            Question q4 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q4);
            Question q5 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q5);
            Question q6 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q6);
            Question q7 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q7);
            Question q8 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q8);
            Question q9 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q9);
            Question q10 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q10);

            Question q11 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q11);
            Question q12 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q12);
            Question q13 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q13);
            Question q14 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q14);
            Question q15 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q15);
            Question q16 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q16);
            Question q17 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q17);
            Question q18 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q18);
            Question q19 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q19);
            Question q20 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q20);

            Question q21 = new Question("A is correct", "Disagree Strongly", "Disagree moderately", "Neutral", "Agree Moderately", "Agree Strongly", 1);
            addQuestion(q21);

        }

        private void addQuestion(Question question) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION, question.getQuestion());
            cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1, question.getOption1());
            cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2, question.getOption2());
            cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3, question.getOption3());
            cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4, question.getOption4());
            cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION5, question.getOption5());
            cv.put(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR, question.getAnswerNr());
            db.insert(QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        }

        List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
            List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
            db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Question question = new Question();
                    question.setQuestion(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION)));
                    question.setOption1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1)));
                    question.setOption2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2)));
                    question.setOption3(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3)));
                    question.setOption4(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4)));
                    question.setOption5(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION5)));
                    question.setAnswerNr(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR)));
                    questionList.add(question);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            c.close();
            return questionList;
        }
    }
```

QuizActivity Class

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewQuestion;
    private TextView textViewScore;
    private TextView textViewQuestionCount;
    private TextView textViewCountDown;
    private RadioGroup rbGroup;
    private RadioButton rb1;
    private RadioButton rb2;
    private RadioButton rb3;
    private RadioButton rb4;
    private RadioButton rb5;
    private Button buttonConfirmNext;

    private ColorStateList textColorDefaultRb;

    private List<Question> questionList;
    private int questionCounter;
    private int questionCountTotal;
    private Question currentQuestion;

    private int score;
    private boolean answered;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        textViewQuestion = findViewById(R.id.text_view_question);
        textViewScore = findViewById(R.id.text_view_score);
        textViewQuestionCount = findViewById(R.id.text_view_question_count);
        textViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
        rbGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        rb1 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button1);
        rb2 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button2);
        rb3 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button3);
        rb4 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button4);
        rb5 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button5);
        buttonConfirmNext = findViewById(R.id.button_confirm_next);

        textColorDefaultRb = rb1.getTextColors();

        QuizDbHelper dbHelper = new QuizDbHelper(this);
        questionList = dbHelper.getAllQuestions();
        questionCountTotal = questionList.size();
        Collections.shuffle(questionList);

        showNextQuestion();

        buttonConfirmNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!answered) {
                    if (rb1.isChecked() || rb2.isChecked() || rb3.isChecked() || rb4.isChecked() || rb5.isChecked()) {
                        checkAnswer();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Please select an answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    showNextQuestion();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void showNextQuestion() {
        rb1.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb2.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb3.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb4.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb5.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rbGroup.clearCheck();

        if (questionCounter < questionCountTotal) {
            currentQuestion = questionList.get(questionCounter);

            textViewQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
            rb1.setText(currentQuestion.getOption1());
            rb2.setText(currentQuestion.getOption2());
            rb3.setText(currentQuestion.getOption3());
            rb4.setText(currentQuestion.getOption4());
            rb5.setText(currentQuestion.getOption5());

            questionCounter++;
            textViewQuestionCount.setText("Question: " + questionCounter + "/" + questionCountTotal);
            answered = false;
            buttonConfirmNext.setText("Confirm");
        } else {
            finishQuiz();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void checkAnswer() {
        answered = true;

        RadioButton rbSelected = findViewById(rbGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        int answerNr = rbGroup.indexOfChild(rbSelected) + 1;

        if (answerNr == currentQuestion.getAnswerNr()) {
            score++;
            textViewScore.setText("Score: " + score);
        }

        showSolution();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void showSolution() {
        rb1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        rb2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        rb3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        rb4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        rb5.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        switch (currentQuestion.getAnswerNr()) {
            case 1:
                rb1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                textViewQuestion.setText("Answer 1 is correct");
                break;
            case 2:
                rb2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                textViewQuestion.setText("Answer 2 is correct");
                break;
            case 3:
                rb3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                textViewQuestion.setText("Answer 3 is correct");
                break;

            case 4:
                rb4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                textViewQuestion.setText("Answer 4 is correct");
                break;

            case 5:
                rb5.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                textViewQuestion.setText("Answer 5 is correct");
                break;
        }

        if (questionCounter < questionCountTotal) {
            buttonConfirmNext.setText("Next");
        } else {
            buttonConfirmNext.setText("Finish");
        }
    }

    private void finishQuiz() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the layout file as well

Comment: Noted will be Shared in a minute